# Tense in clause with thought

Tags: difference, tense, past-tense

I have a situation as below:

My father don't know that my mom go to the supermarket. They meet accidentally at that supermarket. When seeing my mother, my father would say to my mother

> I thought you (had gone)/ (went) to your friend's house. what are you doing here?

I should use (had gone) or (went) for this situation?
Are both fine for this situation?, If so, what is the differences?

Comment: Either one makes sense to me.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPITALS in your titles.  This is the second time you've done it.

Comment: "My father _doesn't know_ that my mom _has gone_ to the supermarket." _I thought you had gone_ would be the most idiomatic to me.

Comment: Dear James K 
I wont use ALL CAPITALS in my next posts

Comment: Dear Kate Bunting ,
Some say that either works, some say only "had gone" works. I am a little confused.